# Where did IPv5 go?

Tags: networking, standards, ipv6, ipv4

Since we are all moving towards IPv6 whether we want it or not, I ask this: what happened to IPv5? Was it not cool enough for it's older brother, or did something else happen to that specification?

Comment: We... would rather not talk about that-version-which-shall-not-be-mentioned.

Comment: Technically I think IPv6 would be IPv5's *younger* brother. =)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leisure_Suit_Larry_4:_The_Missing_Floppies

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe the answer lies in the "[What ever happened to IPv5?](http://www.oreillynet.com/onlamp/blog/2003/06/what_ever_happened_to_ipv5.html)" blog post over on http://www.oreillynet.com

To quote:

> In the late
>   1970’s, a protocol named ST — The
>   Internet Stream Protocol — was created
>   for the experimental transmission of
>   voice, video, and distributed
>   simulation. Two decades later, this
>   protocol was revised to become ST2 and
>   started to get implemented into
>   commercial projects by groups like
>   IBM, NeXT, Apple, and Sun. Wow did it
>   differ a lot. ST and ST+ offered
>   connections, instead of its
>   connection-less IPv4 counterpart. It
>   also guaranteed QoS. ST and ST+, were
>   already given that magical “5″.

Comment: Ok then.  What happened to IPv3?

Answer (score 5):

IPv5 doesn't exist. The Internet Protocol version number 5 was used by a different protocol called ST.

> Its second version, known variously as ST-II or ST2, was drafted by Topolcic and others in 1987 and specified in 1990. In RFC 1819, ST2 distinguishes its own packets with an Internet Protocol version number 5, although it was never known as IPv5.

[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Stream_Protocol)